# (Ubuntu dualboot) I've lost my Windows 10 boot option and boot-repair doesn't fix the problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

Not sure why my windows boot option is missing but I've tried some of the normal options, os-probe, update-grub, boot-repair, with no success. See below for output of boot-repair which shows it can detect the windows partition but it isn't added to the grub menu!

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20210316_1900]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

User choice:

Is nvme0n1 (1TB PCS PCIe M.2 SSD) a removable disk? no



Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of
nvme0n1p5 into the MBRs of all disks (except live-disks and removable disks without OS).
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix


Quantity of real Windows: 1
WinSE in sdb1
/mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/ may need repair.
/mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/bootmgr may need repair.

==> Reinstall the GRUB of nvme0n1p5 into MBRs of all disks (except live-disks and removable disks without OS)

======================= Reinstall the grub2 of nvme0n1p5 =======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.9

==> Reinstall the GRUB of nvme0n1p5 into the MBR of sda

grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
Exit code: 1

======================= Reinstall the grub2 of nvme0n1p5 =======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.9

==> Reinstall the GRUB of nvme0n1p5 into the MBR of sdb

grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Sector 48 is already in use by the program `FlexNet'; avoiding it.  This software may cause boot or other problems in future.  Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track.
Installation finished. No error reported.

======================= Reinstall the grub2 of nvme0n1p5 =======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.9

==> Reinstall the GRUB of nvme0n1p5 into the MBR of sdc

grub-install /dev/sdc
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
Exit code: 1

======================= Reinstall the grub2 of nvme0n1p5 =======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.9

==> Reinstall the GRUB of nvme0n1p5 into the MBR of nvme0n1

grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-1042-oem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.6.0-1042-oem
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-60-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[329178]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 79673: /bin/sh

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme0n1 (1TB PCS PCIe M.2 SSD) disk!

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at sector 
    1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    config script
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d root 
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS CurrentSession on nvme0n1p5
OS#2:   Windows 10 on sdb1

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic root=UUID=b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7


===================================== UEFI =====================================

This installed-session is not in EFI-mode.
EFI in dmesg.
[    0.005585] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000D14302C0 000042 (v01                 00000000      00000000)



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdc1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdc1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sdc

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xa774f2d9
          Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
nvme0n1p1         2048    1050623    1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
nvme0n1p2      1052670 2000408575 1999355906 953.4G  5 Extended
nvme0n1p5 *    1052672 2000408575 1999355904 953.4G 83 Linux
Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 14336C3A-757E-4D05-874E-DD32B7E47BD1
      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 223.58 GiB, 240056327680 bytes, 468860015 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x3e272cc7
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1  *         2048 467803866 467801819 223.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdb2       467804160 468854783   1050624   513M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
Disk sdc: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 50AC817A-1F86-4FF2-A136-CE6D0A9FF3F0
      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sdc1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1:;
1:1049kB:1000GB:1000GB:ext4::;
sdb:240GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA SanDisk SDSSDA24:;
1:1049kB:240GB:240GB:ntfs::boot;
2:240GB:240GB:538MB:ntfs::msftres;
sdc:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA HGST HTS541010A9:;
1:1049kB:1000GB:1000GB:ntfs::msftdata;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:msdos:1TB PCS PCIe M.2 SSD:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32::;
2:539MB:1024GB:1024GB:::;
5:539MB:1024GB:1024GB:ext4::boot;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL   PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                    
└─sda1      ext4     e586ab44-fcf1-42ff-a26e-5b72692580c1 1f677323-269d-4a27-a470-27b41651b6b3 VAULT   
sdb                                                                                                    
├─sdb1      ntfs     82669A45669A39BD                     3e272cc7-01                          WINDOWS 
└─sdb2      ntfs     5CE04A69E04A498A                     3e272cc7-02                                  
sdc                                                                                                    
└─sdc1      ntfs     3BEEF9900826B292                     a904c999-1faa-4df4-a6e8-9673062b013f GAMES   
nvme0n1                                                                                                
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     CBFC-BACE                            a774f2d9-01                                  
├─nvme0n1p2                                               a774f2d9-02                                  
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d a774f2d9-05                                  

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                   Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme0n1p1           511M   0% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
nvme0n1p5         231.5G  70% /
sda1              523.5G  38% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sdb1                139G  38% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
sdb2               88.9M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
sdc1              217.2G  77% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc1

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1         rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
nvme0n1p5         rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
sda1              rw,relatime
sdb1              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdb2              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdc1              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-45-generic   b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-44-generic   b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.6.0-1042-oem   b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-60-generic   b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=b9b4e301-b20c-4ca2-b44b-da7b0d01cf5d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 212.728542328 = 228.415533056  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 221.164459229 = 237.473529856  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 225.784496307 = 242.434256896  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  33.747211456 = 36.235792384   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-60-generic                  1
 767.981807709 = 824.614187008  boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-1042-oem                    1
 612.971954346 = 658.173624320  boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-44-generic                  1
 225.784496307 = 242.434256896  boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic                  1
 612.971954346 = 658.173624320  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 226.221992493 = 242.904014848  boot/initrd.img                                3
 344.892177582 = 370.325155840  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-60-generic               1
 344.852714539 = 370.282782720  boot/initrd.img-5.6.0-1042-oem                 1
 344.650722504 = 370.065895424  boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-44-generic               2
 226.221992493 = 242.904014848  boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic               3
 344.650722504 = 370.065895424  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17622 Aug 17  2020 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Aug 17  2020 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Apr 15  2020 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Apr 15  2020 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Apr 15  2020 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15  2020 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Apr 15  2020 41_custom


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p2

00000000  17 20 b7 5e a5 5f ce 91  ce 18 9a 2b a3 85 44 0d  |. .^._.....+..D.|
00000010  9e 5f 0e d4 a5 76 3a 5a  1d 15 69 19 5a c0 03 62  |._...v:Z..i.Z..b|
00000020  2a 81 12 3b b5 0a 28 02  3b 15 86 c2 d0 a1 2d 1f  |*..;..(.;.....-.|
00000030  ae 20 ce a4 f7 8c 0a 86  80 f4 6d e6 f2 42 df da  |. ........m..B..|
00000040  4d 80 68 af a8 ac bd d7  02 00 56 82 9b 6a 98 76  |M.h.......V..j.v|
00000050  9f 09 d3 61 cc 5b c7 57  68 62 e7 4d 45 52 ef 5e  |...a.[.Whb.MER.^|
00000060  41 e8 3d 9d 16 96 f1 66  ce 2a 1c 03 05 6f 40 19  |A.=....f.*...o@.|
00000070  10 59 f6 da 2e 6b 29 66  4b e9 5e b2 4a cd e3 e8  |.Y...k)fK.^.J...|
00000080  b6 69 55 49 b7 c6 54 cf  6a 10 64 1b fa a9 54 9e  |.iUI..T.j.d...T.|
00000090  fc 00 5d 6e e8 27 5c 6d  d2 0f ad 99 35 76 34 27  |..]n.'\m....5v4'|
000000a0  f5 0c 5b b6 6c 59 44 62  ba 5c 26 6d c4 8a 37 ee  |..[.lYDb.\&m..7.|
000000b0  07 57 30 9c 8e 5c ab 56  10 c4 2f f4 8e bd 9c 79  |.W0..\.V../....y|
000000c0  2b 2b 96 12 7a 8b ae 3d  eb d8 da 66 07 b7 89 1a  |++..z..=...f....|
000000d0  d2 f6 af 48 ad 0d d4 9d  ab 49 fa 34 0b f4 1e a0  |...H.....I.4....|
000000e0  56 3d 2b c3 65 40 81 55  ac 36 b9 01 4b 20 f5 6d  |V=+.e@.U.6..K .m|
000000f0  d5 30 73 45 a9 99 d8 10  19 a8 b7 c1 30 30 68 55  |.0sE........00hU|
00000100  80 ba c4 27 b3 16 6f fa  30 0e ce c2 7d a0 70 d0  |...'..o.0...}.p.|
00000110  3a 1f d9 c6 21 3b f4 5e  0a 95 a0 2e 93 17 0a e3  |:...!;.^........|
00000120  b2 42 2f 48 a4 14 74 0c  41 6d b6 02 12 9a 41 c7  |.B/H..t.Am....A.|
00000130  c0 dd e6 2b 5b 6e ab 45  f7 20 b3 ba 82 2c 5a 41  |...+[n.E. ...,ZA|
00000140  67 8b 0c fc d1 10 3a 51  b1 37 52 8b 1e dd 44 a7  |g.....:Q.7R...D.|
00000150  34 e9 de 26 cb d0 a7 10  65 49 1d 95 40 c9 f5 c0  |4..&....eI..@...|
00000160  da 5b 5c e4 87 7e 66 9b  ab ba 1a ab d0 07 6a dd  |.[\..~f.......j.|
00000170  db 99 04 bd 67 75 e0 37  11 e6 e5 a8 18 a8 65 53  |....gu.7......eS|
00000180  af c6 2e 9b 20 e4 32 1a  bc 26 1e 27 7c 66 54 d8  |.... .2..&.'|fT.|
00000190  59 f6 5a e4 13 98 78 53  44 0b 87 f6 55 38 80 89  |Y.Z...xSD...U8..|
000001a0  58 f3 1b ea 74 99 92 8c  0b 6c c0 91 94 5d 69 3a  |X...t....l...]i:|
000001b0  28 6d 6b 7a 9a 9b 2a eb  91 7e c1 9a ef 5e 80 fe  |(mkz..*..~...^..|
000001c0  c2 ff 83 fe c2 ff 02 00  00 00 00 c0 2b 77 00 00  |............+w..|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sdc1

00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 08 00 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  ff 5f 70 74 00 00 00 00  |........._pt....|
00000030  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff 05 47 07 00 00 00 00  |..........G.....|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  92 b2 26 08 90 f9 ee 3b  |..........&....;|
00000050  00 00 00 00 0e 1f be 71  7c ac 22 c0 74 0b 56 b4  |.......q|.".t.V.|
00000060  0e bb 07 00 cd 10 5e eb  f0 32 e4 cd 16 cd 19 eb  |......^..2......|
00000070  fe 54 68 69 73 20 69 73  20 6e 6f 74 20 61 20 62  |.This is not a b|
00000080  6f 6f 74 61 62 6c 65 20  64 69 73 6b 2e 20 50 6c  |ootable disk. Pl|
00000090  65 61 73 65 20 69 6e 73  65 72 74 20 61 20 62 6f  |ease insert a bo|
000000a0  6f 74 61 62 6c 65 20 66  6c 6f 70 70 79 20 61 6e  |otable floppy an|
000000b0  64 0d 0a 70 72 65 73 73  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  |d..press any key|
000000c0  20 74 6f 20 74 72 79 20  61 67 61 69 6e 20 2e 2e  | to try again ..|
000000d0  2e 20 0d 0a 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |. ..............|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[329178]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 66035: /bin/bash
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You tried a BIOS repair to a UEFI system. You have to always boot in UEFI mode. How you boot repair flash drive UEFI or BIOS for both Windows & Ubuntu is how it repairs. Reboot in UEFI mode & rerun Boot-Repair. It will not fix Windows issues. If booting from UEFI boot menu can you not directly boot Windows? Do not post entire Boot-Repair report, but post the pastebin site it gives you for the report.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I will try booting into UEFI usb live Ubuntu and boot repair again. I cannot boot windows at all even through UEFI boot menu. I will use paste bin next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Rescatux to fix the grub. It works like a charm.

Comment: Except [in your own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/768427/86440) ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Nothing is gonna work everywhere. But Rescatux is a good first try.