# Debian 12 bricked (won't boot). How to unbrick it?

Tags: debian, boot, boot-loader

**How the brick happened:**

1. I have a SSD with a recently-installed UEFI Debian 12 (Kingston SA400S37120G). It was working just perfect; until
2. I swapped temporarily the SSD by a HDD with Debian 11;
3. When I swapped the SSD back, the Debian 12 is nowhere to be found on the motherboard Boot Settings (Asus Crosshair V Formula-Z). I get only a cursor when trying to boot again, or nothing, depending on the settings I choose. But no Debian 12 at all.

**Why I can't unbrick:**

1. When my Debian 11 bricked (most commonly on similar circumstances, like swapping by a Windows HDD), I quickly fixed it every time using a Rescatux thumb drive.
2. However, Rescatux won't work with my new graphics card (Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650).
3. Therefore, I don't have the easy Rescatux unbricking path at hand anymore, and don't know what to do without it.

**Question:**

1. Which information is needed to understand what happened, and how to get it?
2. What can I do in order to unbrick my Debian 12 install?

**Additional information:**
[Boot Info Summary @ Paste.Debian](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/514a2a69/)

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred Information added to the question, as requested.

Comment: You are missing the grub or debian entry in UEFI. Often removing a drive, then requires you to add that entry again. You can use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. Grub uses efibootmgr to add entry to UEFI. Or since the rest of your grub looks correct, you can just use efibootmgr to add entry. See `man efibootmgr`. Example, but your folder in ESP is Debian. You can name entry grub or debian, your choice.

Comment: @oldfred Running `Boot-Repair` unbricked the Debian 12. I'm using it now to reply. [Report](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/5c559d51). Thank you very much! Would you like to formally provide an answer to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot-Repair is for Linux systems. It really just updates grub or offers to reinstall grub or a few other settings. Will not fix Windows issues, unless the update to grub finds a Windows entry. Must be sure to boot in same boot mode as install. Most systems now are UEFI boot.

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Very occasionally the default fix may not be best choice & then advanced mode required. Best then that someone knowledgeable on boot issues reviews report to confirm best fix.

If just UEFI  boot entry missing, then the install of grub installs a new UEFI boot entry using efibootmgr. You can do that yourself. See:

```
man efibootmgr
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/668506/changed-the-uefi-motherboard-on-a-dell-laptop-now-it-says-no-os-detected

Comment: What made me repairing allowable by you? Were the lines on the report "_No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda._" and "_Suggested repair: The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of sda2, using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi_" and "_Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file_" ? I'm asking to prevent the need to create a new question every time Debian 12 bricks again, which, in my past experience with Debian 11, will not be rare or infrequent.

Comment: With UEFI, no boot files should be in MBR. The gpt protective MBR only exists so old MBR partitioning tools do not try to partition drive. It only has one entry saying entire drive is gpt. All boot files are in ESP - efi system partition. You only were missing entry in UEFI. `sudo efibootmgr -v` which is in report. The rest of grub looked correct, but full reinstall of grub makes sure of that. Often Boot-Repair just suggest a grub update which would not add a new entry in UEFI. Not sure how you lost UEFI entry? Did you remove drive as that often causes UEFI to forget entries?